# Alphabetica sorting in acro package

Tags: sorting, acro

I have the following code and can't find out the command to sort my abbreviation list alphabetically.

```
\documentclass [11pt, a4paper] {article}

\usepackage{acro} %list of abbreviations
\acsetup{first-style=short} %list of abbreviations

\input{abbreviations.tex} %define abbreviations in this file.

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}List of Abbreviations}
\acuseall %to make all abbreviations appear in list of abbreviations (formally uses all of them)

\printacronyms[heading=none,include-classes={abbrev},sort=true] % print list of abbreviations

\end{document}
```

Currently, the compiled document looks like this:

[image]

**EDIT**

Here are some lines from the `abbreviations.tex`:

```
%------------------------------------
% DEFINING ABBREVIATIONS
%------------------------------------
\DeclareAcronym{1}{ % every abbreviation must be defined this way
    short = {LDL} , % abbreviation shown in the list of abbrev
    long  = {Low-density lipoprotein} , % long text shown in the list of abbrev
    class = {abbrev}
}
\DeclareAcronym{2}{
    short = {HDL} ,
    long = {High-density lipoprotein},
    class = {abbrev}
}
\DeclareAcronym{3}{
    short = {RYGB} ,
    long = {Roux-en-Y gastric bypass},
    class = {abbrev}
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a few lines from `abbreviations.tex`?

Comment: @egreg I added the three first entrees

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first argument to `\DeclareAcronym` is used for sorting.

```
\documentclass [11pt, a4paper] {article}
\usepackage{acro} %list of abbreviations

\acsetup{first-style=short}
%\input{abbreviations.tex} %define abbreviations in this file.

\DeclareAcronym{LDL}{ % every abbreviation must be defined this way
    short = {LDL}, % abbreviation shown in the list of abbrev
    long  = {Low-density lipoprotein}, % long text shown in the list of abbrev
    class = {abbrev}
}
\DeclareAcronym{HDL}{
    short = {HDL},
    long  = {High-density lipoprotein},
    class = {abbrev}
}
\DeclareAcronym{RYGB}{
    short = {RYGB},
    long  = {Roux-en-Y gastric bypass},
    class = {abbrev}
}
\begin{document}

\acuseall

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}List of Abbreviations}
\printacronyms[heading=none,include-classes={abbrev},sort=true]

\end{document}
```

Note the final changes.

[image]

### Update

With new versions of the `acro` package, something has changed. In particular, the ID is no longer used for sorting, but `short` is. However, one can add a `sort` key to solve sorting issues. If not specified, the entry is sorted by the `short` key. Also `classes` now is `tag` and `include-classes` is `include`. In the example code below, the `sort` keys are commented because not really needed.

```
\documentclass [11pt, a4paper] {article}
\usepackage{acro} %list of abbreviations

\acsetup{first-style=short}
%\input{abbreviations.tex} %define abbreviations in this file.

\DeclareAcronym{LDL}{ % every abbreviation must be defined this way
    short = {LDL}, % abbreviation shown in the list of abbrev
    long  = {Low-density lipoprotein}, % long text shown in the list of abbrev
    tag = {abbrev},
    %sort = {LDL},
}
\DeclareAcronym{HDL}{
    short = {HDL},
    long  = {High-density lipoprotein},
    tag = {abbrev},
    %sort = {HDL},
}
\DeclareAcronym{RYGB}{
    short = {RYGB},
    long  = {Roux-en-Y gastric bypass},
    tag = {abbrev},
    %sort = {RYGB},
}
\begin{document}

\acuseall

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}List of Abbreviations}
\printacronyms[heading=none,include=abbrev,sort]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The sorting mechanism of `acro` seems to have changed . With newer versions (as far as I could tell, with the update to version 3?), the alphabetical order seems to be determined using the value of `short` instead of using the `ID`. You might want to externd your answer with a short remark on that change.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks for noting. I also added some more changes.