# Why is my list of abbreviations not in alphabetical order?

Tags: acro

I am using the [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro?lang=en) package to generate a list of abbreviations for acronyms used in my thesis. Specifically, the `\printacronyms` command in the [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro?lang=en) package prints the list. I am also using the [`chemmacros`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros?lang=en) package to typeset chemical formulas.

With inspiration from [this code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345726/15622), here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
  barriers/use, barriers/reset,
  use-id-as-short,
}

\DeclareAcronym{CH3CN}{
  short = \ch{CH3CN},
  long-indefinite = an,
  long = \iupac{aceto|nitrile},
}

\DeclareAcronym{EMI+BF4-}{
  short = \ch{EMI+ BF4-},
  short-indefinite = an,
  long = \iupac{1-ethyl-3-methyl|imida|zolium tetra|fluoro|borate},
}

\DeclareAcronym{DFT}{
  long = density functional theory,
}

\begin{document}

\acuseall

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}List of Abbreviations}
\printacronyms[heading=none,sort=true]

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Why does "DFT" come after "EMI+BF4-"?  According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345726/15622), "The first argument to `\DeclareAcronym` is used for sorting." If that were the case, wouldn't "DFT" come before "EMI+BF4-"?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to determine the order in which acronyms are sorted, the `acro` package takes into account the value of `short`. Since the short form of the first two acronyms contains a command (namely `\ch`), they are placed in the "special caracter"  section of the list of acronyms, which means at the very beginning (even before the letter "a"). In order to sort them alphabetically, you can use the `sort` key with values as shown in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
  barriers/use, barriers/reset,
  use-id-as-short,
}

\DeclareAcronym{CH3CN}{
  short = \ch{CH3CN},
  sort = CH3CN,
  long-indefinite = an,
  long = \iupac{aceto|nitrile},
}

\DeclareAcronym{EMI+BF4-}{
  short = \ch{EMI+ BF4-},
  sort = EMI+BF4-, 
  short-indefinite = an,
  long = \iupac{1-ethyl-3-methyl|imida|zolium tetra|fluoro|borate},
}

\DeclareAcronym{DFT}{
  long = density functional theory,
}

\begin{document}

\acuseall

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}List of Abbreviations}
\printacronyms[heading=none,sort=true]

\end{document}
```