# Latex: acro prints abbreviations list out of order when special characters are involved

Tags: acro

I am using the `acro` package in Latex, and would like my list of abbreviations to print alphabetically (the default usage of `\printacronyms`). However, one of my abbreviations is in italics, and `acro` appears to be reading the leading `\` of `\textit` and placing this entry out of alphabetical order. Is there a way to place this entry in the appropriate location in the list?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{pfpr}{
  short=\textit{PfPR\textsubscript{2-10}},
  long=\textit{Plasmodium falciparum} parasite rate among 2-10 year olds,
}
\DeclareAcronym{covid}{
  short=COVID,
  long=Coronavirus disease,
}
\DeclareAcronym{par}{
  short=PAR,
  long=Population at Risk,
}


\begin{document}

\printacronyms

\section{Main Text}
\ac{covid}, \ac{par}, \ac{pfpr}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output when compiling in Overleaf]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 3):

As I learned from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570872/why-is-my-list-of-abbreviations-not-in-alphabetical-order), the solution is to use the `sort` tag in `\DeclareAcronym`, like so:

```
\DeclareAcronym{pfpr}{
  short=\textit{PfPR\textsubscript{2-10}},
  sort=pfpr,
  long=\textit{Plasmodium falciparum} parasite rate among 2-10 year olds,
}
```

[image: Corrected output]